# submit a form according to the selected item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

i have a problem, i have a menu retrieved from database
i want to submit form to php page by post according to the selected item
every time i click the a href link "Add" the value of the post is the only the first item in menu

```
while($MenuItem=mysql_fetch_array($rc))
                                {   

                                ?>

    <!--To send item info to single-product page -->                        
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="products">
                <!-- <a href="single-product.php" > -->
                <a href="single-product.php?id=<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>">
                    <img src="images/<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Image']; ?>"  alt="" />
                </a>                            
                <a href="single-product.php?id=<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>">
                    <h4> <?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Name']?> </h4>
                </a>
                <p class="price"> <?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Price']?></p>
                <div class="row lead">
                    <center><div id="stars" class="starrr"></div></center>
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="AddtoCart.php" id="productFrom">
                <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>" name="CC" />   
                </form>
                <a class="view-link shutter" href="javascript: submitForm();" name="Add">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add To Cart</a>                            
        </div>  <!-- End of /.products -->
   </div> <!-- End Of /.Col-md-4 -->
```

Comment: Where is your `submitForm()` function?

Comment: you have an action attribute on your form, why won't you just have a submit input in your form?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function submitForm() ('#productForm').submit();</script>

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and saying that your `form` has a hardcoded `id` attribute, which is the same for all your forms.  Your `submitForm` function is probably using `getElementById`, which will find only the first one, then submit it.  You'll need to introduce some uniqueness to each form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeating over a number of items and writing out elements.  One of those elements is a form:

```
<form method="post" action="AddtoCart.php" id="productForm">
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>" name="CC" />
</form>
```

However it has a hardcoded `id` attribute - `productForm`.  This means that each of the forms in your page has the same ID, which is not valid - IDs are meant to be unique.  The `submitForm` function is getting hold of the form by ID, so will always find the first one with that ID and submit it, hence your problem.

To solve this, each form needs to have a unique ID:

```html
<form method="post" action="AddtoCart.php" id="productForm<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>">
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>" name="CC" />
</form>
```

And this needs to be passed into your `submitForm` function:

```html
<a class="view-link shutter" href="javascript: submitForm('<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>');" name="Add">
```

which can then be adjusted to use it:

```js
function submitForm(formID) {
    $('#productForm' + formID).submit();
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that `$MenuItem['Item_ID']` is numeric.  If there's a chance it may contain `'` or `"` etc, you'll need to use a loop counter to identify each form instead.

Comment: yes its numeric, i did as the above but now the form cannot submitted

Comment: @cat23 Must just not be finding the form to submit then.  Can you check the output of the php script to ensure that the forms actually written out have the unique IDs?